# Running .exe applications with wine embed

Tags: wine, executable

Is possible to "bind" a .exe application with a "Wine Portable version" to run it in a ubuntu system? avoiding installation of Wine?

Comment: It's [possible](https://wiki.winehq.org/Portability) but not practical because the resulting standalone application would be huge and the Wine portability project is still in an early stage of development.

Comment: Thanks, karel, I will try this. Actually I want to run a compiler program(not for a MSWin executable, but only avaliable for MSWin) and I just need the CLI to run, graphical interface isn't needed.